# How to bind action or mutation result with any navigation emitter in ReactorKit

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I want to merge `ReactorKit` with `RxFlow`. Is there an elegant idea how to bind any action or mutation to steps emitter likes `PublishRelay` inside of `Reactor`

My sample

```swift
import ReactorKit
import RxFlow

class ViewModel: Reactor, Stepper {
  let steps: PublishRelay<ItemsStep>

  enum Action {
    case itemSelected(Item.ID)
  }

  enum Mutation {
    case itemSelectionResult(Item.Details) // ??
  }

  func mutate(action: Action) -> Observable<Mutation> {
    switch action {
    case .itemSelected(let id):
      return ItemsService.fetch(by: id)
        // ... ??? bind(to: steps)
        // ... ??? map(Mutation.itemSelectionResult)
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to avoid observable `do` methods with self capturing like

```swift
  func mutate(action: Action) -> Observable<Mutation> {
    switch action {
      case .itemSelected(let id):
        return ItemsService.fetch(by: id)
          .do { [weak self] info in
            self?.steps.accept(ItemsStep.details(info))
          }
          .map(Mutation.itemSelectionResult)

    }
  }
```

Comment: Why do you have `let steps: PublishRelay<ItemsStep>` in your Reactor in the first place? That doesn't feel right.

Comment: @DanielT. Because of this component emits information about navigation, and as I understand correctly it should be out of presentation side. Any action which could be sent to reactor can effect to steps directly or lazy after some task execution like in my sample. I forgot add in my sample that my ViewModel implement navigation protocol